# Binding change event on table value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am new to Angular and I need help on writing an event that can pass the changed value from the table to my component.
Below is the table cell so that when the user changes that value, it should pass it to the component.ts.

HTML:

```html
<tbody contenteditable='true'>

  <tr *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected">

    <td input type="text" (ngModelChange)="saveCalendar($event)" [ngModel]="name.value" *ngFor="let name of item.results" name="promoOne" ngDefaultControl>
      {{name.value}}

    </td>

  </tr>

</tbody>
```

Component.ts:

```js
saveCalendar($event): void {
  console.log("Updated Value" + this.tableValue); // updated value
  this.body = {
    "promotionname": this.promotionname,
    "period": this.period,
    "indicator": this.indicator,
    "value": this.value
  };
  this.services.saveCalendar(this.body)
    .then(
      response => {
        if (response == "Success") {
          this.firstPage(this.clickedItem);
        }
      }
    );

}
```

But it is not triggering the event.
Please help me if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that your HTML is formatted correctly. Try adding the input inside of a table cell. The name attribute must also be unique:

```html
<tbody>

  <tr *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected">

    <td>
      <input type="text" *ngFor="let name of item.results" (ngModelChange)="saveCalendar($event)" [ngModel]="name.value"  [name]="name.value"/>
    </td>

  </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: then it is not running the for loop for every cell in a table. is it possible to do it for:                                                                                         
             <td (ngModelChange)="saveCalendar($event)" 
           [ngModel]="name.value" *ngFor="let name of item.results" 
                                          name="promoOne" ngDefaultControl />
                                                                         {{name.value}}
                                                                </td>

Comment: I have amended my answer.

Comment: Now it is binding the same value to all table cells

Comment: I have created a small example here. We can edit this to achieve your goal: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vssxxy

Comment: This is not working as expected.
Below is the code I am using.

JSON:

[{"topic": "Billboards", "results": [{"period": "02-03-17", "value": "1469664.00"}, {"period": "09-03-17", "value": "1603582.50"}]}, {"topic": "CBSE", "results": [{"period": "02-03-17","value": "6391248.00"}, {"period": "16-03-17", "value": "7563528.00"}]}]

Comment: the html and component is the same. HTML:   <tr *ngFor="let item of calendarTableSelected">
 <td>
   <input (ngModelChange)="saveCalendar($event)" [ngModel]="name.value" *ngFor="let name of item.results" name="second" ngDefaultControl/> 
</td>
 
</tr>

Comment: I have updated the example. The event is triggered using your JSON value and HTML. Please verify: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwggpt

Comment: I am retreiving  JSOn from the service.  
            firstPage(clickedItem){
  this.calendarService.paginationFirst(clickedItem).subscribe(data => this.calendarTableSelected = data);
  console.log ("Data from actual first page" + this.calendarTableSelected);}                                                                                           How to integrate this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169458/discussion-between-peter-and-neha-uniyal).